# How to stop event from firing when hiding element in a change event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I've found a bug when I'm using a keyboard to select from a select drop down, the form containing the drop down is submitted, this only happens on IE. The drop down is in a div and has a JS handler for the change event.

In the handler the div containing the drop down is hidden, this causes a submit event to be triggered on whatever is currently focused on.

The problem can be solved by hiding the div from outside the context of the change event (using a setTimeout) but this doesn't explain why the issue is occurring.

Simplified example (the issue persists if jQuery is not used):

```
<form>
  <div id="container">
    <select id="select"></select>
  </div>
</form>

$("#select").on('change', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#container").hide(); <-- this causes the form to be submitted
})
```

Hiding the div shouldn't cause the form to be submitted, only IE and mobile browsers are showing this issue.

Edit: 
This is on IE 11 and Edge, I can get the same issue on 10 and 9 using the IE 11 emulator, I haven't tried lower versions.

More code:

```
<form>
    <div class="selectAddress u-hidden m-form-row m-form-row--full-width" style="display: block;">
        <label class="a-label" for="Contact_PolicyHolderAddress_FullAddress">Please select your address</label>
        <div class="m-form-row__content">
            <span class="a-dropdown">
                <select aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" class="a-dropdown__select addressList" id="Contact_PolicyHolderAddress_FullAddress"
                    name="Contact.PolicyHolderAddress.FullAddress">
                    <option aria-label="Please select" value="">Please select....</option>
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option value="Address not found" class="notFound">Address not found</option>
                </select>
                <input class="addressList" id="Contact_PolicyHolderAddress_FullAddress" name="Contact.PolicyHolderAddress.FullAddress"
                    type="hidden" value="">
                <span class="a-dropdown__ui"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the validation of the form selecting an element in the dropdown. What version of IE are you using? Are you able to reproduce this with only the code you've provided (adding some `<option></option>` of course)

Comment: add submit function prevent default action happen no submit and in submit function set validation.

Comment: I try to make a test with this code. https://textuploader.com/1an27 I just add one more function to catch the submit of form. But in testing I find that Form not get submitted while hiding the container. Can you please try to make a test with this code to check the result. If issue persist than please try to inform us, Which exact version of MS Edge you are using currently. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to stop the event propagation :

```
$("#select").on('change', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: If the problem is caused by `$("#container").hide()`, this will fire its own event with its own propagation which would not be stopped by this solution. I'm unable to test this, however, because I cannot reproduce the bug.